# Programmatically sorting with blank cells

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm sorting a table using multiple columns via the setSort function, which is called when a dropdown box changes. In the code below, the ward column contains some null values.

```
patientTable.setSort([
    { column: 'name', dir: 'asc' },
    { column: 'ward', dir: 'asc' }
])
```

The problem is that all the null values appear at the top of the list when ordering ascending. I know that you can use **alignEmptyValues** when using one of the built in sorters to force empty cells to the bottom. Is there a way of doing this when using the setSort function? I can't find anything in the documentation, and adding alignEmptyValues to the objects doesn't appear to do anything.

I'm using Tabulator version 4.9.3 in Edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is set `alignEmptyValues` in the column definition, then when you sort, either by clicking the column header, or programmatically with `setSort`, it will move the empty values as defined.

```js
var data = [
    {name:"Tom",   ward:"A"},
    {name:"Dick",  ward:"B"},
    {name:"Harry", ward:"C"},
    {name:"Larry", ward:""},
    {name:"Moe",   ward:"A"},
    {name:"Curly", ward:"C"}
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:data,
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Ward", field:"ward", sorter: "string", sorterParams: { alignEmptyValues:"bottom" } },
    ],
});

document.getElementById('sort').addEventListener('click', ev => {
    table.setSort([
        { column: 'name', dir: 'asc' },
        { column: 'ward', dir: 'asc' }
    ]);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>

<br>
<button id="sort">Set Sort</button>
```

Comment: Fantastic, that did what I want. Thank you very much!